# How to attach DB by installshield?

Tags: c#, sql, database, windows, installation

i'm creating an install program by install shield 2010. i have 2 problem:

1. how can i make my installation to install SQLExpress as a prerequisite?
2. i add the following SQL script in Script tab in installshield SQL script part:

   ```
   Use master
   go
   CREATE DATABASE [DBClinic] ON
   (FILENAME =N'%appfolder%ClinicSoftware\DB\DBClinic.mdf'),
   (FILENAME =N'%appfolder%ClinicSoftware\DB\DBClinic_1.mdf')
   FOR ATTACH
   go
   ```

while installing, it shows the this error:

```
  unable to open the physical file "C:\Program files\Clinic\DB\DB.mdf".
  operating system error 2: the system cannot find the file specified (5120)
```

this path is created during the installation. when i saw the error i checked the path, and it was there but when i accept the error and installation canceled, the install path vanish too.

if before completing the installation, the install path does not create physically, how can i attach my DB in during installation?!?!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when Im trying to attach a .mdf file, I have one solution, it is necessary to specify "Full control" permission for the .mdf and also for the installation directory (for the ´Authenticated users' group), then it worked. But i unfortunately need to do attach WITHOUT a permission setting. :-(((